# NSURLSession request HTTPBody becomes nil in Custom NSURLProtocol

Tags: nsurlsession, nsurlprotocol

In my application, I am performing POST using NSURLSession.

Steps followed:

1. Setting Header
2. Setting HTTPBody
3. Making POST request using NSURLSession.

The code is:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{ @"searchTerm": @"shampoo", @"sort": @"Most Reviewed" };
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"SomeURL"]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:10.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
request.HTTPBody = postData;

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                if (error) {
                                                    NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                } else {

                                                    NSLog(@"Pass");
                                                }
                                            }];
[dataTask resume];
```

Now in custom NSURLProtocol class:

```
(BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {

    if ([request.HTTPMethod isEqualToString:@"POST"]) {
    //here request.HTTPMethod is coming nil
    //Whereas my requirement is to get request.HTTPMethod which got     request parameter.
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *request.HTTPBody

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555018/why-is-the-httpbody-of-a-request-inside-an-nsurlprotocol-subclass-always-nil

Comment: Short answer: By the time you get to a protocol, the data object has been converted into a stream, which you have to read from.

Comment: Solution is we have to perform [self.request.HTTPBodyStream open]; and then try to access it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the HTTPBody of a request inside an NSURLProtocol Subclass always nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555018/why-is-the-httpbody-of-a-request-inside-an-nsurlprotocol-subclass-always-nil)

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, body data objects get transparently converted into streaming-style bodies by the URL loading system before they reach you. If you need to read the data:
Open the HTTPBodyStream object
Read the body data from it
There is one caveat: the stream may not be rewindable, so don't pass that request object on to any other code that would need to access the body afterwards. Unfortunately, there is no mechanism for requesting a new body stream, either (see the README file from the CustomHTTPProtocol sample code project on Apple's website for other limitations).